# On what objects are variables within local scope of functions defined on?

Tags: javascript

So in this code below, on what object is `y` defined on? It outputs to three as seen below; of course var y is locally scoped, so I thought of the variable y as scoped to the object `s` or `x`. but still gives me `undefined`.. I know that `alert(y)` will give me three but that is not my question. I'm wondering on what object it is defined on if it is locally scoped in a function like the code below.

```
var s = function x() {
    var y = 3;
    alert(y); // y is defined on what object? //results 3
    alert(window.y); //local scope so obviously this won't be true
    alert(s.y); //undefined? why //expected 3 
    alert(x.y); //undefined? why //expexted 3
}
s();
```

Comment: This one seems to a be a good read for scope and context: 
https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of it like this - every time you call a function, a new anonymous object is created containing all of the local variables of the function.

When you say `s.x`, it refers to the function `s` (which is also its own object), but not to the anonymous object from the previous paragraph.. Note how there is only one `s` function, but it can be called many times, each time creating a new anonymous object.

Here's how your code actually looks* behind the scenes:

```
var s = function x(_ctx) {
   _ctx.y = 3;
   alert(_ctx.y); // locals are looked up in _ctx
   alert(window.y); // 
   alert(s.y); // not looking in _ctx, but in s
   alert(x.y); // ditto, as x === s
}

s({});
```

*) well, in a way..

Comment: thanks! great help. so how can i access that "anonymous object's" local variables? Also I'm wondering why at the global scope (_ctx.y) and (s.y/x.y) all refer to to the object window? basically why it's not the same case as here or is there actually something else happening behind the scenes that I'm not aware of?

Comment: so globals are in another "globals object".. in browsers it's called window, but that is just a name given to it, and the name simply comes from the property of the global object (so, in addition to `window`, you can also obtain it with e.g. `window.window.window`). As for accessing the locals object, the spec explicitly says "It is impossible for an ECMAScript program to access an execution context.", so no luck.. (the most you can get is the magic arguments variable, but that doesn't contain the locals, just arguments to the function, and with no names as well..)

Comment: this really cleared up things for me... I wish books would explain like that, they state that local variables are scoped to the function, but not the function's PARAMETER'S OBJECT. Do you have any recommendation for a good reference book that teaches/shows behind the scenes like that or a good book for learning javascript concepts like that?

Comment: sorry, I can't recommend a book, as I haven't read any (on Javascript, I mean :).. If you really want the details, the language specification might be a good read.. This stuff is in chapter 10..

Comment: ok thanks. do you also know other good resources?(not necessarily books.)

Comment: nope.. :) I just pick it up as I go, and if/when I get confused, I look at the language spec.. If I stumble upon anything, I'll let you know!

Comment: I have one more question, I'm wondering why i can't do this var x = {
x.room = "jhg"
};
alert(x.room); the same syntax for defining properties but on objects (i know how to properly initialize objects using key/value pairs). I'm assuming in this case it's because the object isn't initialized with this syntax, so it's undefined when trying to access the property?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159183/discussion-between-xs0-and-user8783104).

Answer (score 2):

`y` in declared in the scope of `function x`. It is not related to any object. `s` is the same `x`. It refers to a function. Functions are callable objects which can have it's own properties assigning via `s.y` or `x.y`, but everything which is declared in it via `var, const, let` or `function` is not related to its object itself, but it's context. So the `y` is a simple variable, just scoped in the context of the `function`.

Comment: i don't understand why the variables here are not properties of the function x since functions are objects

Comment: @user8783104 Functions are objects and you get add properties to that object basically through the `object.prop` syntax. But you are just declaring simple variable like your function `x`, only with one difference that your `y` is not visible outside of the function.

Comment: yeah i understand that i can access properties through oboj.prop which is  exactly why I'm confused why a variable is not considered a property here and cannot be accessed likewise.

Comment: The function only decreases the access for that variable, it not add to its object

Comment: ok thanks then why are variables at the global scope added to the window object? and not have their access "increased"?

Comment: `window` is another case. You don't need to compare this two. Everything which is related to the global scope is related to `window`. If you will remove the `var` part from the variable declaration in the function in not strict mode, it also will be added into `window`.